# Django 1.8: Message in Class-Based View Not Displayed

Tags: python, django

I am writing a simple website using Django 1.8.6 (Python 3.5.0) for rental service. After user created a rent (using a class-based `CreateView`), user is redirected to rent's index page where a "success" message should be displayed (the index template inherits from `base.html`).

I read documentation for Django's [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/messages/) and the relevant section for [adding messages in class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/messages/#adding-messages-in-class-based-views).

I added the relevant parts to my code, but after creating a rent, the message is not displayed. the `<div id="messages">` (from `base.html`) is rendered in HTML but no message is displayed (because `success_message` is not processed in `RentCreateView`).

My settings:

**settings.py (according to docs no additonal setup necessary for Django 1.8):**

```
...
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'rental_service',
)
...
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    ...
)
...
TEMPLATES = [
     {
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
     },
]
```

**base.html (iterates over the messages):**

```
...
<div id="messages">
    {% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
        <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
</div>
...
```

**rent_list.html (extends base.html):**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
...
```

**views.py (uses success_message attribute provided by SuccessMessageMixin):**

```
class RentCreateView(CreateView, SuccessMessageMixin):
    model = Rent
    fields = [
        "timestamp_rent",
        "timestamp_return",
        "customer",
        "rental_examples"
    ]
    template_name_suffix = "_create_form"
    success_message = "Rent created successfully." # Ignored: even if "def get_success_message(self, cleaned_data): raise Exception()"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(RentCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("rental_service:rent_index")
```

Comment: Flip around the inheritance order, i.e. `(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView)`. `SuccessMessageMixin` overrides `form_valid()` and you get a diamond inheritance problem with `CreateView`.

Comment: I noticed too late: It's --of course-- not diamond inheritance. `CreateView` inherits `FormMixin` and `FormMixin.is_valid()` is a dead end. Hence the MRO problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [dhke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3191557/dhke) for pointing me in the right direction because of the method resolution order problem.

Flipping around the inheritance order solves the problem:

**views.py:**

```
class RentCreateView(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    ...
```

BTW: it should be documented that order of base classes is significant when [adding messages in class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/messages/#adding-messages-in-class-based-views).

Comment: The order is actually important for any Mixin that (potentially) overrides functionality of a base class. It might seem natural to put the base class first and then the Mixins, because the mixins "only" *add* functionality (it does to me) . Of course, that's usually the wrong way round.